# Grunt-Mocha `PhantomJS timed out`

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, phantomjs, mocha.js

I keep getting this message while runnign my mocha tests from grunt.

```
Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.
```

The tests ran fine in the browser, however they fail to start from grunt. I've been using [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-mocha) Grunt plugin for running my brower tests , and my this is the relevant parts of my Gruntfile.js.

```
// I've checked if it does server while my tests are running & it does
connect: {
  test: {
    // public is where all my files are, of course
    base: 'public', 
    port: 8080
  }
},

mocha: {
  client: {
    urls: ['http://0.0.0.0:8080/test.html'],
    log: true,
  }
},
```

Here's the `test.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mocha Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mocha.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.run();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the `public` directory

```
/public
- index.html
- test.html
 /css
  - main.css
  - mocha.css
 /js
  - main.js
  - test.js \\ contains main.js + mocha.js + my tests
```

Here's the output from grunt following up to the fail.

```
Running "uglify:dev" (uglify) task
File public/js/main.js created.
File public/js/test.js created.

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:8080

Running "mocha:client" (mocha) task
Testing: http://0.0.0.0:8080/test.html

Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

All the src I need for the tests is put in a single file it includes my source (and it's dependencies), mocha, and the tests.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it is still relevant to you, but just in case anyone else faces this issue:
In my case, the tests worked perfectly fine if I directly called them from command line, like: `mocha-phantomjs .\test\src\tests.html`. It was only that `grunt-mocha` was unable to run them, throwing this error.
Shifting to [`grunt-mocha-phantomjs`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-mocha-phantomjs) fixed it for me, no code change required. Gruntfile looks like this:

```
mocha_phantomjs: {
    all : ["./test/**/*.html"]
}
```

(You may have to escape that property name if you have set `camelcase` to `true` in your jshint settings though.)

Comment: My JSHint settings have set `camelCase` to `true`. How can I use this Grunt task without changed my JSHint settings?

Comment: @JN11 add `/* jshint camelcase: false */` before mocha_phantomjs and `/* jshint camelcase: true */` after the `}` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

`mocha.run()` only works when running tests in the browser.

To run tests in the browser *and* grunt do this:

Replace `mocha.run()` with:

```
if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
    mochaPhantomJS.run();
}
else {
    mocha.run();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I've already tried this (forgot to mention it I guess), unfortunately it doesn't change anything for me.